# suggested category and subcategory drop down list on resourcetrade.earth

Tags: jquery, list, select, dropdown

I like to implement same drop down list as "Commodity" on https://resourcetrade.earth/data

It has 2 features,
1. select and select back function
2. key in keywords; related categories, sub-categories and commodities show up

Could you please let me which third party component has these functions? or any guide how to implement it?

Thanks,

Shenyi

[KeyIn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCbGO.png)
[Select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQuUO.png)

Comment: Looks like you need a programmer

Comment: Asking for suggestions for a resource or third party component is considered off-topic here, and I have voted to close the question for this reason.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try to implement it first if no one knows third party library could be used to simplify the implementation.